# Python kivy: replacing label in a button function

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to kivy and am creating a pace calculator for Track and field through Python and kivy. I have a button named "Calculate" That when you press on, it should show the time for different distances based off of a total time(ex: 200m, 400m). Below is the .py code that I used to define the on_press()

```
class CalculatorScreenBelowMile(Screen):
def press(self):
    eventlistbelow = ['event100split', 'event200split', 'event300split', 'event400split']
    resultsbelow = self.ids.inputbelow.text
    for i in range(len(eventlistbelow)):
        self.ids.i.text = resultsbelow
```

Below is the part of my .kv file with these events:

```
Button:
text: "Calculate"
on_press: root.press()
```

and

```
LabelSplits:
        id: event100split
        text: ""
        pos_hint: {'x': .21, 'y': .60}
    LabelSplits:
        id: event200split
        text: ""
        pos_hint: {'x': .21, 'y': .45}
    LabelSplits:
        id: event300split
        text: ""
        pos_hint: {'x': .21, 'y': .30}
    LabelSplits:
        id: event400split
        text: ""
        pos_hint: {'x': .21, 'y': .15}
```

Don't worry about the indentation too much because it got kind of messed up when copying and pasting.

The function press() works with just one event, ex: self.ids.event100split.text = resultsbelow
but, I have no idea how to work through all of the events in a loop.

I get the warning:
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'. Did you mean: '**setattr**'?

I can provide the full code if needed.

Comment: you don't have enough code for a working example, that would help.  In your case you might want a ListProperty.  a starting point, at the top of your .kv file kv_labels: [event100split, event200split, event300split, event500split]  and in your Python widget class definition,  kv_labels = ListProperty().  in your imports 'from kivy.properties import ListProperty'
and then you can loop through that list and each item in your list will be a label